# The type or namespace name 'Hardware' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, cs0246

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Hardware' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) **in visual c#**
When we run this program in Visual Studio 2k19 in C# Console application There is problem showing :
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Hardware' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OOP1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hardware hf = new Hardware();   // error in this line

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

--------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OOP1.com.inventoryMsystem
{
    class Hardware : Product
    {

        public Hardware()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hardware");
        }
    }
}

----------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OOP1.com.inventoryMsystem
{
    class Product
    {

        public Product()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you place that line with code? Also it seem like you just dont have dll in reference.

Comment: Simply include the `OOP1.com.inventoryMsystem` namespace in your `using` block. You are currently in the namespace `OOP1`, but the class you are trying to use is in `OOP1.com.inventoryMsystem`.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a reference to `Hardware`, which is a class you have created like so:

```
class Hardware : Product
    {

        public Hardware()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hardware");
        }
    }
```

However, the `Program` class, where you are referring to the `Hardware` class, is in a different `namespace` than your `Hardware` class.  `Program` is in the `OOP1` namespace, `Hardware` is in the `OOP1.com.InventoryMsystem` namespace.  Therefore, your `Program` class does not really know what you are referring to.

To solve, add a `Using` statement to your `Program` class, to let this class 'find' your `Hardware` class thus:

`using OOP1.com.InventoryMsystem`

Your completed code for the `Program` class should look very similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    

using OOP1.com.InventoryMsystem;

    namespace OOP1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Hardware hf = new Hardware();   // No error now

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```